# XSL to return a node containing only children that match

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

If I have an XML node that looks like this

```
<node name="a">
  <element ref="bb" />
  <element ref="cc" />
  <element ref="prefix_dd" />
  <element ref="prefix_ee" />
</node>
```

I'd like to write an XSLT to return

```
<node name="a">
  <element ref="prefix_dd" />
  <element ref="prefix_ee" />
</node>
```

Comment: essentially `/child::node()[descendant::node()/@*[starts-with(., 'prefix_')]]`

Comment: +1 for a good question. As result you'll learn to override the identity rule in a wide class of problems like this -- a very powerful technique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Probably one of the shortest such transformations**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()[not(@ref[not(starts-with(.,'prefix_'))])]|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When applied on the provided XML document**:

```
<node name="a">
    <element ref="bb" />
    <element ref="cc" />
    <element ref="prefix_dd" />
    <element ref="prefix_ee" />
</node>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<node name="a">
   <element ref="prefix_dd"/>
   <element ref="prefix_ee"/>
</node>
```

**Explanation**: Modified identity rule.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the identity rule template and one single template to "cut-off" the unwanted elements.

Example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="element[
        not(
            starts-with(@ref,'prefix_')
            )
        ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="/node">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="element[starts-with(@ref, 'prefix_')]"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Is it OK to use `<xsl:copy-of select="current()"/>` instead of the recursive identity matching (`match="@* | node()"`)?

Comment: @corrinado_swam, Well, `copy-of` it is like deep copy, while `copy` is shallow. It depends on your needs. Provide sample.

Comment: For `/xs:schema/child::node()/@name` == "prefix_", I keep the entire node, everything. For `/xs:schema/child::node()/@name` != "prefix_" && `/xs:schema/child::node()/element[starts-with(@ref, 'prefix_')]` then return the `/xs:schema/child:node()` including ONLY the `element[starts-with(@ref, 'prefix_')]`

Comment: @corrinado_swam, Update or create new question. I didn't understand your question.